# Can't change link's title property

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I'm making my website multilingual. Therefore I change the text via jQuery when a language button is clicked. this works very well for all texts but not for title attributes of links which I use for a hover effect in the navigation.

The link looks like this:

```
<div class="nav-container">
  <!-- Navigation for Portfolio -->
  <div class="nav" id="services">
    <a href="#" class="thumb tr" title="Leistungen" key="menu_business"><span><img src="images/menu_icons/services.png" alt="" /></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

for text I use e.g. (which works!):

```
<h4 class="jobtitle tr" key="companyfield">blabla</h4>
```

and my function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // onclick behavior
  $('.lang').click( function() {
    var lang = $(this).attr('id'); // obtain language id

    // translate all translatable elements
    $('.tr').each(function(i) {
      if($(this).attr('key').indexOf("menu_") == 0) {
        $(this).attr('title', aLangKeys[lang][ $(this).attr('key') ]);
      } else {
        $(this).text(aLangKeys[lang][ $(this).attr('key') ]);
      }       
    });
  });
});
```

The array used as a dictionary is initialized here:

```
var aLangKeys = new Array();
aLangKeys['de'] = new Array();
aLangKeys['en'] = new Array();

aLangKeys['de']['menu_business'] = 'Leistungen';
aLangKeys['en']['menu_business'] = 'Business';
```

When debugging the function with Firebug the title is empty, BUT I can see all other attributes such as `href` or `class` correctly.

I tried to read/write the `title` with `.prop` (>= jquery 1.6), `.attr` (< jquery 1.6) and the native JavaScript `.title`. None of it worked.

jQuery includes I use are:

```
<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- jquery tools script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<!-- jqtransform script for forms -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: doesn't help. tried also hardcoding it like `$(this).attr('title','test123');` / `$(this).attr('title',"test123");`

Comment: @Kai - looks to be working here OK: http://jsfiddle.net/2xpHr/. Are there any errors being logged when you click `.lang`?

Comment: @Kai - I've just remade the fiddle as close as I can to your code and it's still working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2xpHr/3/ - please post if there are any errors being thrown and I can take a look.

Comment: @Joe no errors being thrown but also no way to see the title attr change

Comment: @Kai - can't you inspect the element with firebug and see the change? Or, if not, just add `console.log($('.tr:first').attr('title'));` to the end of that function to log the first `.tr`'s title attribute and check to see whether it's in the correct language.

Comment: yes, could inspect it with firebug. title="Leistungen" changes to "Business" just as I want it to...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have the same problem in all browsers?

Comment: @sara.potyscki: yes, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use language code attributes and the language selector:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp

http://api.jquery.com/lang-selector/

You can set the visibility of HTML elements via CSS or Javascript/JQuery, with less code and more flexibility, with something like this:

```
$('.lang').click( function() {
    var lang = $(this).attr('id'); // obtain language id

    // translate all translatable elements
    $('div[lang]').css('display','none');
    $(':lang('+lang+')').css('display','initial');
} );
```

With duplicated html elements (hidden the secondary language via CSS):

```
<div lang="de">blabla deutch</div>
<div lang="en">blabla english</div>
```

Comment: probably no bad idea but still a lot of work do edit now all the stuff I've already been doing...

Comment: see here: http://jsfiddle.net/vmwK5/ looks like :lang is not working as a selector

Comment: uncaught exception: `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: lang`

Comment: Try replace `$(':lang')` with `$('div[lang]')` in your first fiddle and remember to include JQuery :) Now I edit the answer correctly! [http://jsfiddle.net/vmwK5/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/vmwK5/3/)